# Very weird port forward on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a droplet running Ubuntu 13 on Digital Ocean. On it I have a node server running on port 5000.
From the outside I can access that server on port 80, but I don't know what's forwarding the traffic from 80 to 5000.

- I can't connect to port 80 locally from the server with curl, but I can connect fine to port 5000
- I have no nginx running
- iptables -L is empty (no rules)
- if I start nginx with default config I get that default page when I do curl to localhost, but from the outside I still get the content from the server running on port 5000.
- if I stop the server on port 5000 I get no response from the outside connecting on port 80, even if the default nginx is running locally.
- netstat shows no entries for port 80
- nmap run locally shows port 80 is closed (when nginx is stopped).
- a colleague tipped me off to checking for a separate iptables in /etc/rc.local, but there is no such directory on the server

To me all evidence points to something outside of my server is redirecting 80 -> 5000, but Digital Ocean says there is nothing in their environment that's causing this...

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

iptables -L does NOT list prerouting rules by default.

iptables -t nat -L

shows the prerouting rule that forwards port 80 to 5000 on my machine.

Comment: IPTables doesn't list the NAT table by default.